# How Can I capture "HTTP Response" on Gatling script?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, httpresponse, gatling, scala-gatling

I need to capture "HTTP Response" in a Gatling Script, With Response Code, cookies, Response message, Response body, etc..
The HTTP response associated with a HTTP request. I need both in my Gatling Script.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like below

```
 http("Poll")
                .get(Configuration.URL )
                .queryParam("requestor", "Test")
                .check(status.is(200))
                .check(status.saveAs("statusCode")).check(xpath("//somerespone").saveAs("someresponse"))
```